# "Thank you" page should not show when some one types the URL, How would you do this?

Tags: php, javascript, html, seo

I have a website. If some one posts an inquiry it goes to the thank you page 
www.legasy.com/thankyou/ the URL will be like that. When I am analyzing the webmaster tools its showing more thank yous than inquirys.

After filling form fields validating and inserting that values into the table. It will go to thank you page. But if some one types the url it should not go to thank you page. What I can do for this?

Bellow is my code

HTML

```
<form>
 <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="buyer_name" id="buyer_name"  size="31" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
    <tr> <td>Email</td> 
         <td><input type="text" name="buyer_email" id="buyer_email"  size="31" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>Contact No</td>
         <td>   <input type="text" name="buyer_mobile" id="buyer_mobile" size="31" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                        
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
            <div id="post_enquiry"><img src="./images/for_more_det_click.gif" onclick="postBuyerEnquiry();" style="cursor:pointer;"/></div>
          </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function postBuyerEnquiry()
{

    var nametxt = document.getElementById('buyer_name').value;
    var emailtxt = document.getElementById('buyer_email').value;
    var phonetxt = document.getElementById('buyer_mobile').value;
    output ="text";

  if(nametxt=='')
  {
      alert("Please Enter Your Name");
      return false; 
  } 
  else if(emailtxt=='')
  {
      alert("Please Enter Your Mail Id");
      return false;
  }

     else if(phonetxt=='')
     {
          alert("Please Enter Phone Number");
          return false; 
     }
    process = 'loadEvent';
        output = 'text';
      url = "test4.php";        
    $.get(
            url,
            {'act':'SBQF', 
             'name':nametxt, 
             'email':emailtxt,
             'phone':phonetxt,
            },
            function(responseText)
            {
                 window.location.href = '/legasy.com/thankyou/';
            },
            "html"
        );

}
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST['act']) )
{
    $act        =   formatstring($_POST['act']);
}

switch( $act )
{
    case "SBQF":

         $strName         = $_GET['name'];
         $strEmail        = $_GET['email'];
         $strPhone        = $_GET['phone'];
             //Inserting values into the database   
         exit;  
     break;
}
?>
```

or

If anyone type the URL (www.legasy.com/thankyou/) it want to go to the error page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Wrap everything else inside `else`

```
else { // Give this here
    process = 'loadEvent';
        output = 'text';
      url = "test4.php";        
    $.get(
            url,
            {'act':'SBQF', 
             'name':nametxt, 
             'email':emailtxt,
             'phone':phonetxt,
            },
            function(responseText)
            {
                 window.location.href = '/legasy.com/thankyou/';
            },
            "html"
        );
    return false;
}
```

At any time, this gets executed. Also, give a `return false;` in the end of the else part too!

#### Access Denied stuff

If you want the users not access the `www.legasy.com/thankyou/` page directly, you can set a `session`. The moment you do success thing, you can set a session this way.

```
session_start();
if (condition on success)
    $_SESSION["thankyou"] = true;
```

In the `www.legasy.com/thankyou/` page,

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["thankyou"]) && $_SESSION["thankyou"] != true)
{
    header('Location: /error/');
    die();
}
```

Comment: i cant tick your answer time out i'm sorry

Comment: Guess you can go ahead, now! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a `$_SESSION` value on the `thankyou` page. That way, if somebody manually enters the URL without previously having the `$_SESSION['visited']` (visited is just an assoscative value, you don't have to use it), you can use `header()` to redirect them wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !empty($_POST['act']) )
{
    $act        =   formatstring($_POST['act']);
}
else {
    header('Location: www.legacy.com/error');
}
```

Note that someone can still go to the `thankyou` page by spoofing a POST value.

Comment: exit; shout go after header() otherwise the code afterwards will needlessly get processed, and if someone is wanting to spoof POST they can easily have browser reject the HTTP redirect as well.